# A Problem in Need of an Answer

Tags: buddha, teaching, thinking, wheel-of-dhamma

Through many of Yuttadhammo's videos and accesstoinsight, I have learned a vast amount of knowledge on the Buddha's teachings. But I feel like I am causing myself problems.

> 1) I keep on questioning everything I learn in the Dhamma & expanding
>   on my questions through my answers and so on, how can I stop this from
>   happening? How can I limit my questions or is there anything taught by
>   the Buddha or in Yuttadhammo's tradition to help me?
>
> 2) As I have learned a lot (but definitely not all) from the Buddha's
>   Dhamma, I keep on wanting to write down all that I learn but to keep
>   it for myself on remembering the teaching, and I keep on writing long
>   essays then rewriting and editing and adding and shrinking and adding
>   and so on. I continue to do so and I feel like this is a problem, how
>   can I cope with only knowing the teaching in my head than writing it
>   all I learn down or is this not really a problem?

Please help!   Metta

Comment: Btw., giving the questions a traceable titel is helpful for tracing.

Comment: People learn in different ways, some by watching, some by doing, I have found that I personally, and I suspect you as well, learn by teaching. When I write essays like you're describing I am teaching the student within myself and it often allows me to gain a deeper understanding than I had before.

Answer (score 1):

You probably know, you have to practice. 
  You haven't watched Bhante Yuttadhammo's videos on how to meditate? Bhante Yuttadhammo is always talking about how it takes moment by moment experiencial practice to understand the enefable Dhamma.
  We can't read about insights into our own personal habits and beliefs that are below the surface of consciousness,  we have to witness them.

> Here are some specific Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu videos concerning this issue:
>
> ***Intellectual Knowledge of  Insight Knowledge*** 
>   https://youtu.be/_qw0qRro2es
>
> ***Intelligence, Wisdom, and Stupidity***
>   https://youtu.be/gBTOOI1bk-o
>
> ***Overdosing on Study***
>   https://youtu.be/SfG1Dk6yUKE
>
> ***Study of the Dhamma Vs. Practice***
>   https://youtu.be/T2CodNAHzf0
>
> ***Conceptual Truth vs. Ultimate Truth***
>   https://youtu.be/jg48H8VtN9E
>
> ***Why Practice Meditation***
>   https://youtu.be/0rbspa_39EY
>
> ***Basics of Vipassana*** 
>   https://youtu.be/YmcE3TlCDYE
>
> ***One Who Lives By The Dhamma***
>   https://youtu.be/aVWCyaAmgSc
>
> ***How I Became a Buddhist Monk***
>   https://youtu.be/5PajaN34xK8

Comment: Good and useful answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Dhamma is something to be practised. If it is practised it is remembered. This is what mindfulness means. Mindfulness means to remember to practise the teachings.

Answer (score 0):

> A Problem in Need of an Answer

Since you already seem to be following Ven. Yuttadhammo's teachings I would advice doing the online meditation course with Bhante. I'm doing that right now and I highly recommend it. You will have a weekly video session (via Discord or Google Hangouts) with Bhante and he will teach you the Mahasi Sayadaw technique.

May you have a fruitful practice.